# Images not getting swiped?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have made a gallery, in this when i open an image, say image1, in fullview and then swipe in right direction only the image next to image1 i.e image2 comes and the images following image2 are not shown and similar thing happens when i click in reverse direction of image1. 
[image]

**FullimageActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.helloapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Full_ImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    float startXValue = 1;
    ImageView fullImageView;
    int position;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.gallery_one,R.drawable.gallery_two,R.drawable.gallery_three,R.drawable.gallery_four,R.drawable.gallery_five,
            R.drawable.gallery_six,R.drawable.gallery_seven,R.drawable.gallery_eight,R.drawable.gallery_nine,R.drawable.gallery_ten,
            R.drawable.gallery_eleven,R.drawable.gallery_twelve,R.drawable.gallery_thirteen,R.drawable.gallery_fourteen,R.drawable.gallery_fifteen,
            R.drawable.gallery_sixteen,R.drawable.gallery_seventeen,R.drawable.gallery_eighteen,R.drawable.gallery_nineteen,
            R.drawable.gallery_twenty,R.drawable.gallery_twenty_one,R.drawable.gallery_twenty_two,R.drawable.gallery_twenty_three,R.drawable.gallery_twenty_four,
            R.drawable.gallery_twenty_five};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_full__image);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_full__image);
        }

        Intent i=getIntent();
        position=i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter=new ImageAdapter(this);
        fullImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fullImageView);
        fullImageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.images[position]);
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        int orientation;
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            // or = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        }else {
            orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
        }
        // Add code if needed
        setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float endXValue=0;
        float x1=event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
        int action= MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
        switch (action){
            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                startXValue=event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
                return true;

            case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                endXValue = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
                if (endXValue > startXValue) {
                    if (endXValue - startXValue > 100) {
                        System.out.println("Left-Right");
                        if(position-1!=-1)
                        fullImageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position-1]);
                    }
                }else {
                    if (startXValue -endXValue> 100) {
                        System.out.println("Right-Left");
                        if(position+1!=mImageIds.length)
                        fullImageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position+1]);
                    }
                }
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

**fullimage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_full__image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.helloapp.Full_ImageActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ImageAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.android.helloapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public Integer[] images={
            R.drawable.gallery_one,R.drawable.gallery_two,R.drawable.gallery_three,R.drawable.gallery_four,R.drawable.gallery_five,
            R.drawable.gallery_six,R.drawable.gallery_seven,R.drawable.gallery_eight,R.drawable.gallery_nine,R.drawable.gallery_ten,
            R.drawable.gallery_eleven,R.drawable.gallery_twelve,R.drawable.gallery_thirteen,R.drawable.gallery_fourteen,R.drawable.gallery_fifteen,
            R.drawable.gallery_sixteen,R.drawable.gallery_seventeen,R.drawable.gallery_eighteen,R.drawable.gallery_nineteen,
            R.drawable.gallery_twenty,R.drawable.gallery_twenty_one,R.drawable.gallery_twenty_two,R.drawable.gallery_twenty_three,R.drawable.gallery_twenty_four,
            R.drawable.gallery_twenty_five
    };
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        context=c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return images[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240,240));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: use viewPager. [Check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Comment: Why you didn't use ViewPager instead of Gesture detect?

Comment: handling with image in android, you need to think about memory management, especially if you're handling with many image at once. Like the suggestion above, I recommend you to use ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

once you open any image let's assume position is `3`

so go right and display `position+1` image but the value of position is still `3` so next time again on swipe `position+1` mean 4th image will be displayed

Solution : re-assign the new position value to `position` variable or use unary operators i.e. `position--` or `position++`

Comment: but you have to be careful about Array indexes bound

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called ViewPager and it's already implemented in the support library, so you don't have to write all that code by yourself.

References:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html